# how to use paginate by this is not working

Tags: python, django

`views.py` **paginate_by** is not working, and *'if'* statement doesnot work in *'get_queryset'* is there any way to work with this

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'all_users/public/main.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_public:
            post = Post.objects.filter(patient=self.request.user).order_by('-date_posted')
            context = {
                'posts': post,
            }
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        else:
            query = self.request.session['query']
            post = Post.objects.filter(patient=User.objects.get(username=query)).order_by('-date_posted')
            context = {
                'posts': post,
            }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will paginate the queryset that originates from the `get_queryset`. So you can implement the view with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/main.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        ).order_by('-date_posted')
```

It will add the `Page` object to the context with the name `page_obj`. So you can iterate over it with:

```
{% for post in page_obj %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: or with a condition:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/main.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_public:
            qs = qs.filter(
                author=self.request.user
            )
        else:
            qs = qs.filter(
                patient__username=self.request.session['query']
            )
        return qs.order_by('-date_posted')
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: your answer works but I want to add IF-Else condition in this class. IF-Else condition is not working in 'get_queryset'. Can you help me with this?